# File get content via json

Tags: php, codeigniter, json

I have a file text file in which i am saving user id via file_put_contents 
i want to display that user id before sending it to view function 
here is my code 
i try myself bt not geting result....

```
    $name   =   $this->session->userdata('name');
      $id   =   $this->session->userdata('id');

   file_put_contents($filename,json_encode(array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$name)));

   $response = array();
   $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename));
   if ($response->name==1){
      echo $this->session->userdata('name');
   }
   echo json_encode($response);
```

this dont work that i want to display bt if i remove this if condition then i get my result in view file

```
       if ($response->name==1){
         echo $this->session->userdata('name');
       }
```

thanks....

Comment: This needs basic debugging first. What exactly fails when? Does `file_get_contents($filename)` return anything in the first place? If it does, what does `echo json_encode($response);` give you?

Comment: Yet another typo question...

Comment: if i remove this **   if ($response->name==1){
         echo $this->session->userdata('name');
    }** then i get my desired result bt if i dont remove then i can't get result and no error display

Comment: i just want to get data that is saved with 'name' in array

Comment: in the if condition remove echo then check you get your result or not if u get then remove echo comand and store data into session

Comment: yes it work if i remove echo

Comment: thanks i got and idea how to handle this....

Answer (score 0):

im not clear why do you have

```
if ($response->name==1){
```

but any way try this

if you want to prezerve json object stucture you need the second param to be true

```
 json_decode(file_get_contents($filename) ,true);
```

and you need some json headers that you can find in the botom

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
$name   =   $this->session->userdata('name');
$id   =   $this->session->userdata('id');
if(!empty($name)){

    if(!is_file($filename)){
        touch($filename);
        chmod($filename,0777);
    }

    file_put_contents($filename,json_encode(array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$name),true));

    $response = array();
    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename) ,true);
    if (empty($response->name)){  
        echo json_encode(array('error'=>'empty response name'),true);
     die();

 }else{



    echo json_encode($response);
  }

      }else{
    json_encode(array('error'=>'no username'),true)
    }
```

there is my messaging system inside my admin its for codeigniter

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72626795/messaging.zip

Comment: i am actually implementing a chat system, any one can send and receive msg that are storing in text file, so i want to implement this condition to check that id equal then that msg will be shwon to that user otherwise not, by this chat system will convert into a private chat b/t two person that i want to actually do.

Comment: @aysha-ali ok so this shoud chek if the recipient is not empty ? anty way you have mixxed output part json part non json ..  you have some stuff that i dont understand how you want to build because we are using diferent methods.. i have a messageing system for codeigniter i can send it to you if you want but its not ajax for now  and it can be easyly converted ... i will update this post so you have some error debuging

Comment: @aysha-ali i will upload it on dropbox and post a link here

Answer (score 0):

`$response->name` it will be a string, not an int.

Replace:

```
if ($response->name==1){
    echo $this->session->userdata('name');
}
```

With:

```
if ($response->name){
    echo $this->session->userdata('name');
}
```

**Update:**
You stated somewhere in the comments that you want to check for the user id, but in the code you check username. Also inside the `if` condition, you should use data from $response and not the one from session. That said:

```
if ($response->id == 1){
    echo $response->name;
}
```

As a side note, are you sure that `id` and `name` exists in the session ?